# How do I create an javascript object dynamically?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create an object of locations for placing points on a map.

My code is:

```
    var Locs = [{}];
    var title = '', content = '';

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {


      content = '<div id="bodyContent">' +
                '<p><b>' + locations[i][0] + '</b><br />' +
                locations[i][4] +
                '</div>';

         Locs[i]['lat']   = locations[i][1];
         Locs[i]['lon']   = locations[i][2];
         Locs[i]['zoom']  = zoom;
         Locs[i]['title'] = locations[i][0];
         Locs[i]['html']  = content;

    }
```

I keep getting an error: `TypeError: Locs[i] is undefined`
If I replace i with 0 it works for displaying one point on the map.

What I need to output is:

```
var Locs = [
    {
        lat: 45.9,
        lon: 10.9,
        zoom: 3,
        title: 'Title A1',
        html: '<h3>Content A1</h3>'
    },
    {
        lat: 44.8,
        lon: 1.7,
        zoom: 3,
        title: 'Title B1'
        html: '<h3>Content B1</h3>'
    },
    {
        lat: 51.5,
        lon: -1.1,
        zoom: 3,
        title: 'Title C1',
        html: '<h3>Content C1</h3>'
    }
];
```

So I am wondering if someone can explain to me what I don't understand about creating an object dynamically?

Comment: Is `Locs` already defined as a method or something, what happens if you change the name to `location_array`

Comment: I'm not clear on what the problem is.  `Locs = []` then later `Locs.push({ lat: 1, lon: 2, etc })`

Comment: You're currently initializing Locs as an array containing a single object. You should initialize it as an empty array : `var Locs = [];` and then initialize each object, on each iteration : `Locs[i] = {};`

Comment: For each iteration you need: `Locs[i] = {};` to define a new object. `var Locs = []` also,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a new `object` first before accessing that,

```
Locs[i] = {};
Locs[i]['lat']   = locations[i][1];
Locs[i]['lon']   = locations[i][2];
Locs[i]['zoom']  = zoom;
Locs[i]['title'] = locations[i][0];
Locs[i]['html']  = content;
```

If you do not create it then your code would be evaluated like,

```
Locs[i]['lat']
undefined['lat'] //will throw error here.
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error states, you are trying to create new keys to an object that is undefined. Before assigning values to an object, you need to create it.

When you do `var Locs = [{}];`, it creates an array with one empty object, that's why it works when you replace i by 0. You can either add `Locs[i]   = {};` before assigning the latitude to create an empty object, or directly something like: `Locs.push({lat: locations[i][1], long: locations[i][2], ...etc});`

Answer (score -1):

Initiate arrays for each loop. This code will help you:

```
var Locs = [];
Locs[1] = [];
Locs[1]['lat'] = 123;
Locs[1]['long'] = 123;
Locs[2] = [];
Locs[2]['lat'] = 123;
Locs[2]['long'] = 123;
```

Comment: At the very least it should be `Locs[1] = {}`

Comment: Don't use arrays as associative arrays. That's what objects are for.